# How to Export Jobs/Stages Logs from SparkUI of a Databricks Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-ui

In databricls, I would like to export the jobs/stagesd logs that we see in the sparkui to a custom location for analysis. How can we do this?
[image]


Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for the following property in the configuration file.

**spark.eventLog.dir**

Access the location you will get logs.